# Unique validator in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a user sign-up form. One of the things this form must do is enforce the uniqueness of the new user's email address. In other words, the new user's email address must not be an email address already used by someone else.

I haven't yet been able to find an acceptable solution to this problem, which is somewhat surprising given how simple and common this need is (and how simple and easy the solution is in Rails!).

I've seen [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600379/symfony-2-unique-validator), but the problem with that solution is that it seems to validate "uniqueness" not only on the creation of a record, but every time you try to update the record as well. So once a record is saved, you can't update it ever again because it tells you the email address is already being used. (Perhaps I'm implementing their solution wrong, but it doesn't seem like I am.)

Does anyone have a working example (not just a link to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), please, which I've already read) of a uniqueness validator on an entity/form?

Comment: Also, I followed the instructions here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) and same thing: it validates uniqueness, but I get an error when I try to update existing records.

Comment: Are your trying to use the exact same form for both creating and updating?  I think you might want to look at validation groups (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) which allows you to control which constraints are applied for a given use case.

Comment: No, I'm using two different forms. I'll look at validation groups. Thanks.

Comment: Validation groups were the ticket. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, I have it working. The problem I had been having with email uniqueness being "validated" on all user forms, regardless of whether or not I wanted it to be checked there, was something I was able to solve with validation groups. Here's the relevant part of my `User` entity. Notice the `groups={"registration"}` part of the `@UniqueEntity` annotations:

```
/**
 * VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Sorry, this email address is already in use.", groups={"registration"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Sorry, this username is already taken.", groups={"registration"})
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /** 
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @var string $email
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;
```

And my form class (note the last function):

```
<?php

namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('first_name')
            ->add('last_name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password', 'password')
            ->add('athletic_director_email')
            ->add('school')
            ->add('active', 'hidden')
            ->add('transition_key', 'hidden')
        ;   
    }   

    public function getName()
    {   
        return 'vnn_pressboxbundle_usertype';
    }   

    // The following function is what's important here.
    // This tells this form to use the "registration" validation group.
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {   
        return array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration')
        );  
    }   
}
```

And I believe that's it. I don't think I had to do anything special anywhere else.

Comment: The only additional thing you might need to consider is the case where a user wants to change their email.

Comment: This only works when you do a persist + flush and catch the DoctrineException, the $form->handleRequest() can return isValid() as true even if the username of the user already exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode it, like

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($existingUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['email' => trim($form->getData()->getEmail())])) {
          $form->get('email')->addError(new FormError('Email already used'));
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Doctrine, could tou try to set the unique flag in the Entity directly?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique="true")
 */
protected $email;
```

Comment: this flag is only for the database. it creates a unique key but no validation. if you save an entry you will get the following error:
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry